# Swiping on a Label sholud move one view to another

Tags: ipad, label, nstimer, swipe

I have a requirement in which I need to  swipe on a label and  after swiping on it,it should take me to the other view.
Will it be possible. The Label should be self explanatory as it should change the color and should get a blinking effect  so that the user knows to swipe there.

Please suggest me.

Thanks
Rizwan

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to create a gesture and attach that gesture to the uilabel, heres a simple example

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe;
swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(Gest_SwipedLeft:)];
[swipe setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
[label addGestureRecognizer:swipe];
[swipe release];
```

Then simply apply your code to push the next nib

```
-(void)Gest_SwipedLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) sender
UI_iPad_View *controller = [[UI_iPad_View alloc] initWithNibName:@"ipadview" bundle:nil];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

// Cleanup
[controller release], controller = nil;
}
```